# De-activate blinking of fadeToggle

Tags: jquery, html, css

**HTML:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="Button">Button
  <div class="FadeItem">
    <ul>                    
      <li>Main Menu A </li>
      <li class="Button">Main Menu B
        <div class="FadeItem">
          <ul>
            <li>Sub Menu B</li>
            <li>Sub Menu B</li>
          </ul>
        </div>  
      </li> 
    </ul>       
  </div>        
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.button{
  float: left;
}

.FadeItem{
  display: none;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".Button").hover(function(){
    $(".FadeItem").fadeToggle(500);
  });
});
```

As you can see the simple code above fades in the content of some items.
The problem is when I put the cursor over the fadein content it is blinking but I want that the content is displayed without blinking.

Do you have any idea what I need to change in my code to de-activate the blinking?

https://jsfiddle.net/0tfuobpw/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0tfuobpw/3/)**.

The blinking effect comes from the `fade` so if you don't want it you could use simply the jQuery method **[`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)** instead :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".Button").hover(function(){
    $(".FadeItem").toggle();
  });
});
```

Or you could use `show/hide` methods like :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $( ".Button" ).hover(
    function() {
      $(".FadeItem").show();
    }, function() {
      $(".FadeItem").hide();
  });
});
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $( ".Button" ).hover(
    function() {
      $(".FadeItem").show();
    }, function() {
      $(".FadeItem").hide();
  });
});
```

```css
.button{
  float: left;
}

.FadeItem{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="Button">Button
  <div class="FadeItem">
    <ul>     
      <li>Main Menu A </li>
      <li class="Button">Main Menu B

        <div class="FadeItem">
          <ul>
            <li>Sub Menu B</li>
            <li>Sub Menu B</li>
          </ul>
        </div> 

      </li> 
    </ul> 
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Zakaria, when I do it like this the fadeitem completely disappears when I put the cursor on it but it should be displayed as long as the cursor is on it and only disappear once the cursor is off.

Answer (score 5):

**UPDATE:**

You do not need js for this: D

```css
.FadeItem{
  display:none;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.Button:hover>.FadeItem{
  display:block;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="Button">Button

 <div class="FadeItem">
 
  <ul>     
   <li>Main Menu A </li>
   <li class="Button">Main Menu B
  
    <div class="FadeItem">
     <ul>
      <li>Sub Menu B</li>
      <li>Sub Menu B</li>
     </ul>
    </div> 
    
   </li> 
   
  </ul> 
  
 </div> 
 
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Oktay, when I do it like this the fadeitem completely disappears when I put the cursor on it but it should be displayed as long as the cursor is on it and only disappear once the cursor is off.

Comment: @Michi Dude, you can do this with static CSS.

Comment: Hi Oktay, nice solution. I modified your code a little bit here. https://jsfiddle.net/0tfuobpw/24/ My problem is that I want the Menu B1 and Menu B2 appear next to the Menu button. I tried going with "float: left" and "float: right" but could not make it work. Do you have an idea how to solve this with CSS?

Comment: @Michi  
.FadeItem02>ul {
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
}

Comment: It does work but it leaves a space between Main Menu A and Main Menu B. How can I get rid of this space: https://jsfiddle.net/0tfuobpw/27/

Comment: @Michi  https://codepen.io/oktaykose/pen/qXRjNJ

li >.FadeItem > ul {
    position: relative;
    top: -17px;
    left: 90px;
}

Comment: I really like that you've gone for a pure CSS solution here, it's often the best way to go about it. If I could perhaps add a bit of advice? Transition effects on `display:none;` don't work in Firefox, because technically, `display` only has set states making tweening impossible. However you could do this with `opacity` instead (and then user `pointer-events:none` whilst the `opacity` is on 0) to make sure you don't trigger the hover on an invisible element. +1 nonetheless for a very intuitive answer :)

Comment: @Frits Thank you for your comment. Using Javascript affects the speed of the browser, so it is priority css.  Added with transition effect  :D  https://codepen.io/oktaykose/pen/qXRjNJ   
  
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear;

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the blinking effect is thanks to the `.hover()` event you are using. The `.hover()` event triggers every time the mouse is moved whilst on the element specified, which means that every time you move your mouse over the menu (it toggles in, then out, then in, then out, etc).

You can fix this by splitting your `.hover()` function into two separate functions for `.mouseenter()` and `.mouseleave()` like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".Button").mouseenter(function(){
        $(".FadeItem").fadeIn(500);
    });
  $(".Button").mouseleave(function(){
        $(".FadeItem").fadeOut(500);
    });
});
```

[Here's an updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0tfuobpw/8/), alternatively, below is a snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".Button").mouseenter(function() {
    $(".FadeItem").fadeIn(500);
  });
  $(".Button").mouseleave(function() {
    $(".FadeItem").fadeOut(500);
  });
});
```

```css
.Button {
   float: left;
   border: 1px solid red;
 }
 
 .FadeItem {
   display: none;
   border: 1px solid blue;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Button">Button
  <div class="FadeItem">
    <ul>
      <li>Main Menu A </li>
      <li class="Button">Main Menu B

        <div class="FadeItem">
          <ul>
            <li>Sub Menu B</li>
            <li>Sub Menu B</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Lastly, based on your classes in your HTML I would assume that the display effect would need to separate the sub-menu and the sub-sub-menu.

You can do this by changing your selector to include `.children()`

Purely for interests sake, [here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0tfuobpw/9/) and a snippet showing you how to achieve that.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".Button").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).children(".FadeItem").fadeIn(500);
  });
  $(".Button").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).children(".FadeItem").fadeOut(500);
  });
});
```

```css
.Button {
   float: left;
   border: 1px solid red;
 }
 
 .FadeItem {
   display: none;
   border: 1px solid blue;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Button">Button
  <div class="FadeItem">
    <ul>
      <li>Main Menu A </li>
      <li class="Button">Main Menu B
        <div class="FadeItem">
          <ul>
            <li>Sub Menu B</li>
            <li>Sub Menu B</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Frits, thanks a lot for this answer and the additional code. It is exactly what I am looking for. I used your jsfiddle for a new questions. Maybe you can also help me here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45531251/appearing-of-sub-menus-right-next-to-a-menu-button-not-below