# Appearing of Sub Menus right next to a menu button (not below)

Tags: jquery, html, css

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".Button").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).children(".FadeItem").fadeIn(500);
  });
  $(".Button").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).children(".FadeItem").fadeOut(500);
  });
});
```

```css
.Button {
  float: left;
}

.FadeItem {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="Button">Button
  <div class="FadeItem">
    <ul>
      <li>Main Menu A </li>
      <li class="Button">Main Menu B
        <div class="FadeItem">
          <ul>
            <li>Sub Menu B1</li>
            <li>Sub Menu B2</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see the simple code above fades in/out the content of some items.
All this works perfectly so far. When you hover over the button "Main Menu B" the Sub Menus "B1" and "B2" appear **below** the "Main Menu B".

However, I want that those two items appear **right next** of the button "Main Menu B".

Do you have any idea what I have to change in my code to achieve this?

I tried with `display: inline-block` but could not make it work.

**[Sample code Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0tfuobpw/12/)**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Aligning <li> next to each other, not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16285939/aligning-li-next-to-each-other-not-working)

Comment: Do you mean something like https://jsfiddle.net/0tfuobpw/19/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An nice and easy way of doing this would be to make use of your `position` rules.

Like this:

```
.Button {
   float: left;
   position: relative;
}

.Button .Button {
    position: static;
}

.FadeItem {
    display: none
}

.FadeItem .FadeItem {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
    width: 130px;
    height: 100%;
}

ul {
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0tfuobpw/20/), and here's your snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".Button").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).children(".FadeItem").fadeIn(500);
  });
  $(".Button").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).children(".FadeItem").fadeOut(500);
  });
});
```

```css
 .Button {
   float: left;
   position: relative;
 }
 
.Button .Button {
 position: static;
}

.FadeItem {
 display: none
}

.FadeItem .FadeItem {
 position: absolute;
 left: 100%;
 top: 0;
 width: 130px;
 height: 100%;
}

ul {
 margin: 0;
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Button">Button
  <div class="FadeItem">
    <ul>
      <li>Main Menu A </li>
      <li class="Button">Main Menu B
        <div class="FadeItem">
          <ul>
            <li>Sub Menu B1</li>
            <li>Sub Menu B2</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

On a side note, you will notice that I had to take the margin off the `ul` to make sure things fall in line, so if your `ul` in your current stylesheet has not been reset, you might want to consider doing the same.

I've also made liberal use of double calling properties inside the CSS so ensure that `.Button` has a `position:relative;` property, but any subsequent `.Button` inside of it has `position:static;` instead.

This is to ensure that absolute positioning of the sub-sub menu allows it's height to conform to the height of the original `.Button` element and thereby allowing you to move your mouse-pointer in without any hassle.

Comment: Hi Frits, thanks a lot for helping me here. It looks almost the way I wanted it. Right now both the Menu A and B and the Menu B1 and B2 appear next to the button. My goals is that Menu A and Menu B appear below the button and only Menu B1 and Menu B2 appear next to the button. Can I achieve this somehow with your code?

Comment: @Michi - yup :) I've edited my answer and added a different fiddle. Sorry for misunderstanding your original question.

Comment: I've made a slight adjustment to improve the positioning in a subsequent [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/0tfuobpw/23/)

Comment: Looks nice but do you know which changes I have to make in the CSS so the Sub Menu B1 and B2 appear next to the Main Menu B becasue right now they appear next to the "button".

Comment: @Michi Oh I thought that that was what you wanted 0_o - it seems I am making a habit of misreading your intentions - apologies, just remove the  `.Button .Button` rule like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/0tfuobpw/25/) to fix that :)

Comment: Now it is perfect. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

As everything is nested you could go one after another down towards tree using `CSS >` selector and then using `transform` change it position.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".Button").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).children(".FadeItem").fadeIn(500);
  });
  $(".Button").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).children(".FadeItem").fadeOut(500);
  });
});
```

```css
.Button {
  float: left;
}

.FadeItem {
  display: none;
}

.Button > .FadeItem > ul > .Button > .FadeItem {
  transform: translate(60%, -100%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Button">Button
  <div class="FadeItem">
    <ul>
      <li>Main Menu A </li>
      <li class="Button">Main Menu B
        <div class="FadeItem">
          <ul>
            <li>Sub Menu B1</li>
            <li>Sub Menu B2</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Michi if you dont want to transform then use this code using margin .Button > .FadeItem > ul > .Button > .FadeItem {
  position:relative;
  left:60%;
  margin-top:-28%;
}

Answer (score 0):

I have tried doing the same, check out my link: https://jsfiddle.net/djmayank/8omsq7ah/

few changes in css and html part

HTML:

```
<div class="Button">Button
  <div class="FadeItem">
    <ul>
      <li>Main Menu A </li>
      <li class="Button">Main Menu B
        <div class="FadeItem" id="FadeItem2">
          <ul>
            <li>Sub Menu B1</li>
            <li>Sub Menu B2</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.Button {
   float: left;
 }

 .FadeItem {

   display: none;
 }
 #FadeItem2{
   margin-top:-20px;
   margin-left:90px;
 }
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".Button").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).children(".FadeItem").fadeIn(500);
  });
  $(".Button").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).children(".FadeItem").fadeOut(500);
  });
});
```